# $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\sqrt[3]{x}(-1)^{[x]}$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm considering $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\sqrt[3]{x}(-1)^{[x]}$ where $[x]$ is greatest integer function. I think it does exist. I'm having trouble find $\delta$ to prove this.

Comment: Since $x \to 0$ you can just separately do the approaches to $0$ from the left and then from the right. That way you can replace the greatest integer part (for $x$ near but not equal to 0, as usual for limits) by either $-1$ or $0$ depending on which side the approach is from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every $\varepsilon > 0$, if $|x| < \min \{1, \varepsilon^{3} \}$, then $|x^{1/3}(-1)^{\lfloor x \rfloor}| \leq |x^{1/3}| < \varepsilon;$ so the map has limit $0$ as $x \to 0$.

Comment: Where is the $\delta=1$ case coming from?

Comment: That is an arbitrary but suitable estimate for $|x|$.